# enum as a validator

Tags: java, validation, enums

Below is code in one of the methods.Also, there are similar validations scattered across many methods.

```
if (!isAgreeTermsAndConditions()) {
     addException(Messages.AGREE_TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS);
} else {
      if (!validationManager.isValidSsn(getSsn())) {
          addException(Messages.INVALID_SSN);
      }
      if (!validationManager.isValidDate(getBirthYear()) {  
            addPropertyFormException(Messages.INVALID_DATE_OF_BIRTH);                                                                                      
       }
   }  
}
```

As part of refactoring this, I came up with below approach. Basically, moving the validation logic to an enum

```
 class MyFormHandler{
                  public void submitOrder(){
                        MyFormHandlerWorker.SUBMIT_ORDER.validate(this);
                 }

                  public void addItemToCart(){
                      MyFormHandlerWorker.ADD_TO_CART.validate(this);
                  }

                  public void removeItemFromCart(){
                        MyFormHandlerWorker.REMOVE_FROM_CART.validate(this);
                   }
        }

        enum MyFormHandlerWorker{
          SUBMIT_ORDER{
               validate(MyFormHandler fh){
                      //perform validations 
                      if (!fh.isAgreeTermsAndConditions()) {
                          fh.addException(Messages.AGREE_TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS);
                      } else {
                           if (!fh.getValidationManager().isValidSsn(fh.getSsn())) {
                               fh.addException(Messages.INVALID_SSN);
                            }
                            if (!fh.getValidationManager().isValidDate(fh.getBirthYear()) {  
                              fh.addPropertyFormException(Messages.INVALID_DATE_OF_BIRTH);                                                                                      
                            }
                        }  
                   } 
               }
           };

         public abstract void validate(MyFormHandler fh);
        }
```

After moving the validation, `MyFormHandler` looks cleaner, however am not comfortable with the reverse dependency that the enum has with the form handler. As can be seen there are too many `fh.method()` invocations on the enum, suggesting that the code would be better off in the form handler instead.

Any better way to tweak the enum or refactor this?

Comment: Are there many actions that each use many validations, but in different combinations, and all following a similar pattern of if logic

Comment: Yes, there are many actions and each has its own if else if else validation pattern

Comment: Just thinking about it, why have you split out the code - surely a form know how to validate itself. And the flip side is that you have to know what kind of form it is before devising which validator to use, which defeats most of the purpose of having an enum. why not add s validate() method to the form?

Comment: The form handler has around 3000 lines of code with validations scattered along all the way. With many validate() methods in the form, code looks cluttered. I was hoping to move the validaton to separate component, however since the outcome of the validations are nothing but actions on the form (.addExceptions), looks like the form handler itself is the best place to handle these validations. Probably an inner class that encapsulates these validations be a good idea?

Comment: I mean you should make an abstract base class for a FormHandler and create a subclass for each specific form that overrides the validate method. If you have to work out which form handler to use from info in the request (because for example all forms use the same URL), consider the "factory method" pattern